# netstat shows listening on some ports but nmap shows none

Tags: networking, port

Please help me figure out why the destination host shows processes listening on some ports:

[image]

But source host sees all ignored?

[image]

What exactly am I missing?

Comment: Are you mixing local listening sockets with internet open ports? These are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're scanning TCP ports, so half of the netstat output (the `udp` and `udp6` sockets) is already irrelevant.<sup>1</sup>

The only part that applies to your scan is the list of `tcp` and `tcp6` sockets:

[image: Part of OP's screenshot, showing only the 'tcp' entries.]

But all of those sockets are **bound to a specific local address**, and none of them are bound to the `192.168.1.14` address that you were scanning (nor to the wildcard `0.0.0.0` and `::` addresses). They will only accept connections made *to* 127.0.0.1 (or 127.0.0.53 in the last one).

Because they're bound to a "loopback" address, this means the sockets are only accessible from within the same machine, but not over the network.

---

<sup>1</sup> That aside, it is also much harder to reliably scan UDP due to it not having any sort of connection procedure – although the OS will respond with an error to a port without any listeners, there is still no way to distinguish between packets that are quietly dropped by a "closed" firewall and packets that are successfully received but the service simply decides to not reply.